# How to subset and sum a column in R in one line of code

Tags: r, subset

I'm wondering how to combine subsetting my data and summing a column within that subset data in one line. I can easily do it in two, but I have so many dataframes to do this for, so I want to minimize the copy/pasting/slight editing for each dataset.

Here is the two lines of code I know I can do:

```
sumE_df201 = subset(df201, t>=55)
test = sum(sumE_df201)$e
```

I tried to combine them into one as such, and received the following error:

```
sumE_df201 = sum(subset(df201, t>=55))$e
>Error in sum(subset(df201, t >= 55))$e : 
  >$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

If anyone has insight on how to do this properly, I would appreciate it. I'm sure in the end, me doing two lines and copying it for all dataframes would take less time (I edit them with ctrl+f and replace, when I can, but still). But I am trying to improve my R literacy.

Example/junk data here:

```
t= 1:121
e= rnorm(t, mean=t, sd=1)
junk1 = 301:421
junk2 = 501:621
df201 = cbind(t, e, junk1, junk2)
```

Comment: How about `sum(subset(df201, t>=55)[, "e"])`

Comment: Yep! It does. Do you know why indexing that way but not by $ work? Also if you make that an official answer i'll select it haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `$` does not work is that `subset(df201, t>=55)` is an atomic vector, and you can see more help by `?"$"`.

One way is to use indexing

```
sum(subset(df201, t>=55)[, "e"]).
# 5897.988
```

Another way is converting it to a data frame and then using `$`

```
sum(as.data.frame(subset(df201, t>=55))$e)
# 5897.988
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df201 %>%
       filter(t >= 55) %>%
       pull(e) %>%
       sum
```